# Locking considerations for filling a ConcurrentDictionary with database values in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, generics, thread-safety

Is it necessary to use a lock(lockObj){} block when I fill my ConcurrentDictionary here? For a little background this will be used in a MVC application though I suspect the scenario question is relevant for any multi-threaded application.

In searching stackoverflow I didn't find this exact scenario. Where the first time a value is requested from the GetOptionById value is called, it could be called by two separate threads.

1) Would it be considered better practice to make the List objects value a private static that you lock around in hopes of not calling the database multiple times before the ConcurrentDictionary is filled?

2) Is that (#1 above) even necessary or is the ConcurrentDictionary smart enough to work this out on it's own? Thanks in advance for any input.

```
public class MyOptions
{
    static string GetOptionById(int id)
    {
        if (options == null || options.Count <= 0)
            FillOptionList();
        return options[id];
    }

    static void FillOptionList()
    {
        List<MyBusinessObject> objects = DataAccessLayer.GetList();
        foreach (MyBusinessObject obj in objects)
            options.TryAdd(obj.Id, obj.Name);
    }

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> options = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
}
```

EDIT: Thanks everyone for your input, would this be a safer approach?

```
    public static string OptionById(int id)
    {
        if (!options.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            //perhaps this is a new option and we need to reload the list
            FillOptionsOrReturn(true /*force the fill*/);
            return (!options.ContainsKey(id)) ? "Option not found" : options[id];
        }
        else
            return options[id];
    }

    private static void FillOptionsOrReturn(bool forceFill = false)
    {
        List<MyBusinessClass> objectsFromDb = null;
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            if (forceFill || options == null || options.Keys.Count <= 0)
                reasons = DataAccessLayer.GetList();
        }
        if (objectsFromDb != null)
        {
            foreach (MyBusinessClass myObj in objectsFromDb)
                options.TryAdd(myObj.id, myObj.name);
        }
    }

    private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> options = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
    private static object lockObj = new object();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it necessary to use a lock(lockObj){} block when I fill my
>   ConcurrentDictionary here?

No, the methods on this data structure are already thread-safe.

> 1) Would it be considered better practice to make the List objects value
>   a private static that you lock around in hopes of not calling the
>   database multiple times before the ConcurrentDictionary is filled?

Maybe, especially if `GetList` itself were not already thread-safe. Except that what you propose would not work. That `List<MyBusinessObject>` instance is returned from `GetList` so you cannot lock something that does not exist yet. Instead, you would create a separate object for locking purposes only.

> 2) Is that (#1 above) even necessary or is the ConcurrentDictionary
>   smart enough to work this out on it's own?

No, there is no magic that goes on that would somehow cause `GetList` to be executed serially.

By the way, your `GetOptionById` has a race condition. More than one thread could get inside the `if` block at the same time. Your code might attempt to initialize the dictionary more than once.

Answer (score 3):

What you've got definitely isn't safe. Consider:

Threads X and Y both call `GetOptionById` at roughly the same time. X spots that it needs to populate the dictionary, and starts doing so. The first result comes back, and is added to the dictionary.

Y then spots that there's an entry, and assumes that the dictionary is complete - so it fetches the option it's interested in, which probably *isn't* the one which has already been loaded.

This looks like a good candidate for using `Lazy<T>`... you can pick appropriate options there so that only one thread can be populating the dictionary at a time - a second thread would wait until the first one had finished before proceeding. That way the "populate the dictionary" effectively becomes atomic.

If you never need to update the dictionary after the first load, you might even be okay with just a `Lazy<Dictionary<string, string>>` - it's safe to have multiple readers, so long as there are no writers. I *believe* that `Lazy<T>` will handle the memory barriers appropriately.

Comment: Great input, it is likely that the dictionary will need to be updated though not often (maybe once a day tops), in that case will making the Lazy<T> objects collection that I fill from the database private and static to my class will be the best approach?

Comment: @likestoski: Using `Lazy<T>` is still worthwhile, and if you need to update the dictionary then keeping it as a ConcurrentDictionary is a good plan. I'm not sure what you mean by the next part though - unless you plan on trying to prevent the *updates* happening concurrently (what triggers them?) I don't see any need for anything special.

Answer (score 2):

The following issues can happen in your code as is. If they are acceptable, then you are okay, if they are not, then you'll need to use locks.

1. It is possible for multiple threads to realize that `options` is
   null and recreate the dictionary.  This will result in it being
   populated multiple times.
2. It is possible for a thread to read from
   the dictionary while some, but not all, of the items have been
   added.

Answer (score 1):

`ConcurrentDictionary` only offer thread safety for accessing the elements of the list. Your `FillOptionList` method on the other hand could be invoked multiple times from different threads, all happily inserting values into the collection in turns.

What you need to lock to avoid this is not the collection itself but the condition check inside GetOptionById.